# Error while changing the Rails version in the Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am facing a problem when I change my Rails version in Gemfile from 3.2.13 to 4.0.0. These are the issues I am facing:

```
  abcuser@1234:~/Proj2$ bundle install
        Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/
        Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/
        Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/
        Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/

    You have requested:
      rails = 4.0.0

        The bundle currently has rails locked at 3.2.13.
        Try running `bundle update rails`

        If you are updating multiple gems in your Gemfile at once,
        try passing them all to `bundle update`
```

and when run bundle install:

```
abcuser@1234:~/Proj2$ bundle update rails
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/
You have requested:
  eventmachine = 1.0.9.0

The bundle currently has eventmachine locked at 1.0.0.
Try running `bundle update eventmachine`

If you are updating multiple gems in your Gemfile at once,
try passing them all to `bundle update`
```

If I run eventmachine, again it is saying:

```
abcuser@1234:~/Proj2$ bundle update eventmachine
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/
Fetching dependency metadata from http://rubygems.org/
You have requested:
  rails = 4.0.0

The bundle currently has rails locked at 3.2.13.
Try running `bundle update rails`

If you are updating multiple gems in your Gemfile at once,
try passing them all to `bundle update`
```

Please help me, how can I handle the issue?

Comment: Did the trick.. Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try remove Gemfile.lock and re-do a `bundle update eventmachine`